# Selenium/Serenity Bdd - when page too long ( list with 25 items, i encounter RenderedPageObjectView error

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Here are the error message I received

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for net.serenitybdd.core.pages.RenderedPageObjectView$$Lambda$485/21252030@1b9892b4 (tried for 5 second(s) with 50 milliseconds interval)
```

When I try it scroll the screen manual during the execution, the test is passed.
Do I need to insert code to scroll down the view to read the label at the bottom?

because my understanding of serenity is interacting with the DOM instead of UI action - hence it's should be there even when it's not being visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means it was waiting for a condition, but this condition didn't meet, then fired an exception.

Basically, Serenity BDD uses selenium internally and add many convenient methods to make code easy to read. Therefore, serenity code or selenium will interact with DOM (that reflects on UI).

My advice is read the methods guide before applying it to your code. Besides, add needed interactions (scroll to element, wait ...) to help the workflow works well.